# Is possible to edit AppBar icon background?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change the background color only of the icon that is on the leading of the native AppBar of flutter, but I don't know how, does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: could you include some image and code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using flutter 3.3, you could do like:

```
Material(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Im using flutter 3.3

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: `class TestAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const TestAppBar({required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        style: IconButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size(56, 56);
}`

I tried this but to no avail

Comment: Cool it works, it is possible to reduce the background size to the size of the icon or a little bigger?

Comment: for that you should wrap the icon button with sizedbox

Comment: for some reason the size does not decrease, it stays the same

Comment: I managed to reduce the size by removing the material and adding a container above the icon, Thank you for the help

Comment: would you mind to accept it as answer if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

This apparently solves my initial problem

```
leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {...},
            icon: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```